# Laravel Eloquent order by field as 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I have goods table

```
good_link, parent_link, name
sdf-sdfg   ffff         rock    
utyruuur   ffff         qwe     
gfhdfggg   dddd         paper   
sdfghvcx   eeee         water   
ncvbcxvb   dddd         tree    
dsgfdsg    zzzz         sdff
sdfsdff    zzzz         fdgdf
sdfgdgg    zzzz         sdfsdf
dsvfdgg    zzzz         ssdfgr
brtyfgh    zzzz         fgdfgdf
```

How can I order data by parent_link to have data like

```
ffff
dddd
eeee
zzzz
ffff
dddd
zzzz
zzzz
zzzz
zzzz
```

so all goods goes one after another but always with different parent_link(previous row parent_link != next row parent_link, and ordering A-Z has no difference)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing in fact. 
->groupBy('parent_link') work like i need of course but it's not a variant 
I dont understand how I should start

Comment: Every next parent_link should by different with previous

Comment: I think you should add some more context, explaining why you need that, because with the elements available the question doesn't make any sense.  Do you need to group the elements by same parent_link, or do you need to separate them? How should they be separated, they just can't be sequential but aside from that they could be in any order or they should be separated with some logic?

Comment: @gbalduzzi, I don't want to group. I just want sort element in way, where every next parent_link != previous parent_link.

Comment: you want to avoid displaying the same type of items adjacent to each other?  Is the only rule that it cannot be the same as the next?   How many records are you dealing with? Are you ok with them being in a strict sequence or should they be random?

Comment: @Snapey ,yep, avoid same if there still exists different, if not - they can be same. 
Idea in just show different categories in list first, becouse for now I have goods list from first category, then second category, then third...

I want first category, second category, third category, than again first category, second category and etc

Comment: I mean category === parent_link

Comment: But "zzzz" is matching the previous??  Why move the second ffff down that far??  The _Question_ needs to be clearer than what you have.

Comment: Need more details like table and query...

Comment: @RickJames, yes, zzzz matching previous because there's no different on this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL 8+ use simple

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT good_link, 
                     parent_link, 
                     name,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_link) AS rn -- may add any ORDER BY
              FROM source_table )
SELECT good_link, 
       parent_link, 
       name
FROM cte 
ORDER BY rn -- may add any additional expression
```

For MySQL 5+ use ROW_NUMBER() emulation, for example, based on user-defined variables.

Comment: looks right, but try add limit 2 offset 4 like here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c0210a8738fc41632d678cc3f19b808

Answer (score 1):

In **mysql 5.x**

you use user defined variables to add a rownumber for the different parentids.

First you must sort them by parentids, if you have more rows and want another order  for the parentids, you can add another column to the ORDER BY.

Every same parentid gets different rownumbers starting with 0 andincreasing with every row with the same parentid, the last part is to sort them by these rownumbers.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE goods (
>   `good_link` VARCHAR(31),
>   `parent_link` VARCHAR(31),
>   `name` VARCHAR(31)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO goods
>   (`good_link`, `parent_link`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('sdf-sdfg', 'ffff', 'rock'),
>   ('utyruuur', 'ffff', 'qwe'),
>   ('gfhdfggg', 'dddd', 'paper'),
>   ('sdfghvcx', 'eeee', 'water'),
>   ('ncvbcxvb', 'dddd', 'tree'),
>   ('dsgfdsg', 'zzzz', 'sdff'),
>   ('sdfsdff', 'zzzz', 'fdgdf'),
>   ('sdfgdgg', 'zzzz', 'sdfsdf'),
>   ('dsvfdgg', 'zzzz', 'ssdfgr'),
>   ('brtyfgh', 'zzzz', 'fgdfgdf');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   `good_link`, `parent_link`, `name`
> FROM
>   (SELECT 
>     `good_link`, IF(@parentid = `parent_link`,@rn := @rn +1,@rn := 0) rn, `name`,
>     @parentid := `parent_link`  'parent_link'
>    FROM
>      (SELECT * FROM goods ORDER BY parent_link) t1, (SELECT @rn :=0) t2, (SELECT @parentid :='') t3) ta
> ORDER BY rn;
> ```
>
> ```
> good_link | parent_link | name   
> :-------- | :---------- | :------
> gfhdfggg  | dddd        | paper  
> sdfghvcx  | eeee        | water  
> sdf-sdfg  | ffff        | rock   
> dsgfdsg   | zzzz        | sdff   
> ncvbcxvb  | dddd        | tree   
> utyruuur  | ffff        | qwe    
> sdfsdff   | zzzz        | fdgdf  
> sdfgdgg   | zzzz        | sdfsdf 
> dsvfdgg   | zzzz        | ssdfgr 
> brtyfgh   | zzzz        | fgdfgdf
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fa9d2f2c1ecaea6e008606371637c8e)*

Comment: on production it for every request generates new order... looks good, but not work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

this code is tested on mysql db.

if you have  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, you must disable it ...

```
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))
```

then create a stored procedure to make the order you want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE custom_order()
BEGIN

SET @restCount := 1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_result_table
SELECT   * FROM goods group by parent_link order by parent_link;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table
SELECT   * FROM goods;

   WHILE @restCount >0 DO
   DELETE FROM my_temp_table where (name in (SELECT name FROM  my_result_table));
   INSERT into my_result_table(good_link,parent_link,name) select good_link,parent_link,name FROM my_temp_table group by parent_link order by parent_link;

  set @restCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_temp_table);
   END WHILE;
  SELECT * FROM my_result_table;
END
```

then you can call it whatever you want ...

the basic idea is to make two temporally tables, one will hold the result and another to remove moved sorted rows, 
every while loop ... the distinct ordered  rows will be moved from temporally to result table.

please note that in considered the column 'name' as the unique primary key, you can change it to an suitable one.
you also may pass the table name and column name you want to sort by as parameters to the stored procedure ...

i made a table in my db, name it as 'goods' and inserted the exact data you provide.
please let me know if it helps